# Where does this mantra come from?

Tags: mantras, identification-request, prayer, sleep

This is a fairly well-known verse that's recited before bed to ensure good sleep:

> रामं स्कन्धं हनुमन्तं वैनतेयं वृकोदरं |
> शयने यः स्मरेन्नित्यम् दुस्वप्न-स्तस्यनश्यति ‖
>
> rāmaṃ skandhaṃ hanumantaṃ vainateyaṃ vṛkodaraṃ |
> śayane yaḥ smarennityam dusvapna-stasyanaśyati ‖
>
> Praying to Lords Rama, Skanda (Subrahmanya), Hanumantha, Vainateya (Garuda), and Bhima before going to bed daily, ensures a peaceful sleep without disturbing dreams
> <sub>([shloka.com](https://shlokam.org/ramaskandham/))</sub>

Where does it come from? Is it in one of the Puranas, in an Upanishad, or somewhere else? Is it supposed to be part of a longer prayer? I can't find any information as to where it comes from.